# check percona-xtrabackup installed?

Tags: mysql-5.6

I installed percona-xtrabackup on my OEL 7 but how to check whether its installed or not

```
[root@M1 ~]# yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
[root@M1 ~]# su - mysql
[mysql] sudo yum install https://repo.percona.com/yum/percona-release-latest.noarch.rpm
[mysql] sudo percona-release enable-only tools release
[mysql] sudo yum install percona-xtrabackup-80
[mysql] rpm -qa | grep xtrabackup
percona-xtrabackup-80-8.0.7-1.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to check whether it's installed or not

```
[root@tester ~]# yum list installed | grep xtrabackup
```

if it's installed it will display like this :

```
[root@tester ~]# yum list installed | grep xtrabackup
percona-xtrabackup-24.x86_64               2.4.18-1.el6                 @percona-release-x86_64
```

or you can just run the software with argument like this :

```
[root@tester ~]# xtrabackup --version
```

if it's installed it will display content like this :

```
xtrabackup version 2.4.18 based on MySQL server 5.7.26 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 29b4ca5)
```